# perforce - mkdir operation not supported

Tags: permissions, perforce

I'm trying to get perforce working on a new machine. When I try to sync files, I get:

```
/home/user/p4/dev/framework/end.cfg
mkdir: /home/user: Operation not supported
```

My permissions on this folder are:

```
drwxrw-rw-   2 501  20  p4  68 Sep 19 12:13 p4
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88797/how-to-execute-mkdir-in-home-directory

it sounds like the issue is that "/home/user" doesn't exist, and you aren't allowed to create it.

Look very carefully at the real error message you're getting (I'm assuming your user name isn't actually "user") and see if there's a discrepancy between the path causing the error and your actual home directory.  My guess is you've got a typo in your client spec somewhere (probably the Root or possibly the View) and it's telling Perforce to put your workspace files in an invalid path.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was using a workspace from work, which had the home depot as `/home/user/p4`; on my laptop, the *actual* path is `/Users/user/p4`. Thanks for catching my silly oversight. :)

Comment: Careful about using one workspace on multiple different machines -- unless you've got something that's replicating the content between them (or they're pointing to the same filer), things get very confusing very quickly.  If the two different roots are two different physical disk locations, one workspace for each is the way to go.  :)